# The output of the size of the linkedstack is always 0?

Tags: java, data-structures, iteration, size

```
   public static int sizeIter(LinkedStack p)
   { 
    int s= 0;
    if(p.isEmpty())
    return 0;
    else
    {
        while(p.isEmpty()==false)
        {
            p.pop();
            s++;
        }
        System.out.println("iter" + s);
        return s;
    }
}
    //Here's my driver

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedStack l = new LinkedStack();
     System.out.println("Case 1: Size(Iter) = "+ sizeIter(l));
     l.push(5);
     l.push(4);
     l.push(3);
     l.push(2);
     l.push(1);
     System.out.println("Case 2: Size(Iter) = "+ sizeIter(l));
```

The output is always 0. I don't understand. I am trying to find the size of the linkedstack using an iterative method. I checked that the linkedstack is pushing elements but the size still doesn't change.

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: Is it really your intention that your size method always empties the stack?  Technically, once you run `sizeIter()`, the size of that stack *is* always 0...

Comment: Wouldn't that just empty the parameter LinkedStack p instead of the actual LinkedStack l?

Comment: @faria `p` and `l` are both variables pointing to some instance of a `LinkedStack` in memory.  If you empty the object, it's empty, and it doesn't matter which variable you use to access it; it'll still be empty.

Comment: Please post your *exact* code, complete so that I can copy it, compile, and run. If `LinkedStack` is something that you created or copied from somewhere else (not part of the Java distribution), post it, too. Also copy and paste the actual output from your program. The code you posted does not appear likely to produce the output you describe.

Comment: Also, you might try replacing `LinkedStack` with `Stack`. If that works, then there's a problem with your `LinkedStack` implementation.

Comment: Oh! I see the problem now. Thanks! How can I get the size without emptying the stack? I was thinking to make a copy but to make a copy I would need to empty the stack too @azurefrog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In gerneral**
I have not found "`LinkedStack`" in my default Java library, but I found the normal `Stack` in `Java.util`.
**This answer is based on `Java.util.Stack`**
By using `Stack` instead of `LinkedStack` your code worked absolutly fine (Case 1 = 0 and Case 2 = 5)
I changed one line in the driver: `Stack<Integer> l = new Stack<Integer>();`

**Maybe fatal floor of you method**
Your methode emptys the Stack while counting. This is because both methods modify the same spot in memory and you are counting by deleting the elements of the stack.
How you can see it:
add the line `System.out.println("Case 3: Size(Iter) = "+ sizeIter(l));` at the end of the driver
=> This will return "Case 3: Size(Iter) = 0"

**Other Solutions**

- Use the default `.size()` method of `Stack`.
- Use your iterative method and create a deep clone of the stack befor counting with the while loop

**Footnote**
The `else` part of your iterative method is unneccesary because if the `if` evaluates `true` the method retruns anyways.

Comment: Life would have been easier If I could use the stack but I can't. My specific project is to use the linkedstack.  Ya I noticed the problem was emptying the Linkedstack. I don't know any other way that could give me the size without emptying. The only difference between linkedStack and stack is that they are linked and uses nodes. I don't want to post exactly because it could count as plagiarism. Thanks though!!

Comment: @faria if you don't want to share the implemetation of linkedStack I will not be able to help you any further. Anyways good luck with the poject!